# superuser - 1 quest... with new activity

Tags: support

Why does superuser display "1 question with new activity" , why not simply 1 new question.

What is the significance of "activity" here ?[image]

Answer (score 4):

Because there are other tabs which show questions not in the order in which they have been created, but based on their “activity”. An activity could be:

- a totally new question
- revisions made
- bounties placed
- reopened questions
- “bumped questions” (the system automatically bumps older, unanswered questions to the front page, to give them some exposure)

Strictly speaking, of course, the the “with new activity” string could be left out from the *Newest* view.

Comment: but even when a new question has just been posted with no edits and just 1 view (the questioner's itself I guess) , it still shows "1 question with new activity"

Comment: This also counts as a question with new activity.

Comment: @Emiley it is also possible that the question was edited by the person who asked it during the 5 minute grace period, during which edits can be made without being shown in the revision history. See the bottom of this answer on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/159016

Comment: @Mokubai read again : even when a new question has just been posted with no edits and just 1 view (the questioner's itself I guess) , it still shows "1 question with new activity".
You can check for yourself

Comment: @Emiley I know, I've seen it often. During the grace period edits to the question by the original poster appear to cause it to "bump" but do not show in the edit history.

Comment: Emiley - you will never know if that was the trigger - someone could have answered or edited a question way down the page, which wouldn't pop it to the top for 'newest', only for 'active'.

Comment: @Tetsujin This happens for New questions, just posted - no edits , no answers, nothing.

Comment: We could play the "yes it is," "No it isn't" game all day.

Comment: @Emiley Like I already wrote in my answer, it *does* happen for totally new questions, even without edits in the grace period. But I don't know what else to say. Do you consider it a bug? If so, please clarify what the issue is and what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: @Tetsujin you could play it all day !! And your comment was irrelevant...I had already mentioned about answers and edits.

Comment: @slhck Well maybe not a bug ...but expected behavior would be to display "1 new question" instead of  "1 question with new activity" because if posting a question is an "activity" then so is email...but you wont see any notification like "New mail with activity"

Comment: @Emiley Sure, I understand. But then I recommend you make a constructive suggestion and file a bug report on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ – make sure it's not already posted.

Comment: @slhck didn't know about meta.stackexchange.com....will do..thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The wording might be questionable though it isn't objectionable.

It is, as slhck says, to reflect **any** activity, not just new questions.

The other purpose, though, is that clicking that bar doesn't re-fetch the entire window contents, only the new data.

This does mean it often will fetch a spam post that has since been cleared - sometimes they last only a few seconds before being expunged - but it is a bit of a data saving to only fetch the new headers rather than the entire page.